# Why aren't these HTML table's fields calculating on load?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make sure that the second part of function runs, calculating the columns and showing the result at the end of each row?

```js
function sum_row_qty(el, poOrigin) {
  let rowTotal = 0
  if (el) {
    let parent = el.closest("tr")
    parent.querySelectorAll('.size_qty').forEach(function(e) {
        rowTotal += parseFloat(e.value);
    })
    if (rowTotal) {
      parent.querySelector('.qty').value = rowTotal;
    }
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll("#tableRows > tr > td:first-child input").forEach(sum_row_qty);
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:4%; text-align: left">OS</th>
      <th style="width:4%">XS</th>
      <th style="width:4%">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableRows">
    <tr>

      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="14" onchange="sum_row_qty(this);"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="0" onchange="sum_row_qty(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="14" onchange="sum_row_qty(this);"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="0" onchange="sum_row_qty(this);"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When do you call `sum_row_qty()` that's not within itself? Do you realize you're calling it recursively?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @mykaf . The function is called when the table is loaded. Console-logged what's within ```else {}``` and it seems to run once, although there are 2 rows. So, I'm thinking this is not getting the correct the fields' values to sum.

Comment: @mykaf I think the idea is that the function is called from top-level with an empty `el`, which should go into the `else`. Then that calls itself in a loop, which should execute the `if` code.

Comment: Why doesn't the function use the `poOrigin` argument?

Comment: Can you add all the missing functions and variables? Or get rid of the calls to things like `add_to_total()` and `getPoOrigin()` that aren't relevant to the question? We should be able to run the code in the snippet.

Comment: Sorry about that, @Barmar! Just removed them. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Barmar I've removed the unnecessary functions. Any idea on why these are not calculating when there is no parameter passed? Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer proposed by a gentleman on another [platform](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-calculate-these-html-tables-columns/572958/2?u=santosonit):

```js
function sumInputs(row) {
  const inputsArr = [...row.querySelectorAll('.size_qty')];
  return inputsArr.reduce((total, {
    value
  }) => total += parseFloat(value), 0);
}

function sum_row_qty(el) {
  if (el) {
    const currentRow = el.closest("tr");
    currentRow.querySelector('.qty').value = sumInputs(currentRow);
  }
}

tableRows.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => {
  row.querySelector('.qty').value = sumInputs(row);
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:4%; text-align: left">OS</th>
      <th style="width:4%">XS</th>
      <th style="width:4%">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableRows">
    <tr>

      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="14" onchange="sum_row_qty(this);"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="0" onchange="sum_row_qty(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="14" onchange="sum_row_qty(this);"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="0" onchange="sum_row_qty(this);"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```